# iPhone UINavigation Controller xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller

I have an application with a splash screen that presents a login/register page. You can register and login but at the moment you can only navigate back using buttons. This is not pretty. I am trying to add the UINavigationcontroller to the project as this is a standard iOS component.

I have googled and googled and googled but I CANNOT find a simple tutorial for xCode 4.

Can any of you guys point me in the right direction?

Also every time I search for tutorials they are ALL in Xcode 3 and consequently use the interface builder that seems to have been removed. Is anyone else finding this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this one.. ALthough its written way back, but still I think it still useful.

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-transitioning-between-views/

or maybe u can just start doing it and if u stuck somewhere, just post it here.. :)

Comment: thanks. The problem is that this is for a navigation based app. I have a view based app. The add code in root controller.h but i of course have no view controller.h

I found a tutorial here http://humblecoder.blogspot.com/2009/04/iphone-tutorial-navigation-controller.html 

which i was able to follow BUT because that guy doesn't add any other classes I don't know where to add code to viewdidload methods (to make it do stuff after the view has loaded :()

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should point you in the right direction:

http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/iosdev/navigationcontroller/

By the way, Interface Builder isn't *gone* in XCode 4--it's built-in rather than a separate application.

Comment: unfortunately his series ends right before he gets to the good stuff.

Why are ALL the tutorials SO old and out of date? They all have code in them which Xcode tells me is depreciated. 

I am finding iPhone development extremely frustrating. No one seems to want to tell how it is done.

Comment: If it's deprecated why not look at the docs to see what to use instead? Look through apple docs and samples there is a lot there

Comment: thanks @Isaac Overacker. When i followed this tutorial (it is i two part) the NSLog(@"help form demoview controller) is displayed when the application is launched, NOT when transition to the new screen :( do you have any suggestions?

Thanks